# Sorting a dictionary in python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary created from a scrape of our rubbish collection days, i.e. every Monday in the month March and April: ('3 pink': 14 is a Tuesday due to the Monday being a holiday in the UK)

```
'0 black': 9
'0 pink': 2
'1 black': 23
'1 pink': 16
'2 black': 6
'2 pink': 30
'3 black': 20
'3 pink': 14
```

I have spent many hours trying to get this into an order of:

```
'0 pink': 2
'0 black': 9
'1 pink': 16
'1 black': 23
'2 pink': 30
'2 black': 6
'3 pink': 14
'3 black': 20
```

but I cant seem to do it and need some help or ideas please.

Im new to python and have taught myself so far using YouTube etc. hence I am now stuck.

The dictionary is created using:

```
rubbish = {}
for idx in range(4):
    rubbish[str(idx) + " black"] = int(data.select(".normal")[idx].text)
    rubbish[str(idx) + " pink"] = int(data.select(".pink")[idx].text)
```

The idea at the end is to display the date and sack color for the next weeks rubbish collection.

Comment: It seems your only different criteria for the desired order is that ``pink`` comes before ``black``. Why don't you just swap the two insertion statements so that ``pink`` is inserted before ``black``?

Comment: Besides "black" and "pink", would there be other words appearing in the keys?  If yes, what exactly is the rule you'd like the keys sorted?

Comment: At present the dictionary is searched for the next value(int) that corresponds to the todays date.day and displays the color and date for the collection on the Monday. This works when the day is the collection day, but when I try to look for the day coming up i.e 5 or less days before the collection day it will display the color and a message 'next Monday'. (or whatever the day is) This works sometimes, othertimes it will get it wrong due to the fact its looking through the values for a matching next value(int).

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it is to sort the list in the order explained above and then it will take the top value(int) and then set it to delete the key/value pair after its been processed. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

new_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(your_dict.items(),
                              key=lambda x: (int(x[0].split()[0]), x[1])))
```

You might want to keep only a list of key,value pairs:

```
lst = sorted(your_dict.items(),
             key=lambda x: (int(x[0].split()[0]), x[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, the result unfortunately is still wrong, its almost there: ('0 pink', 2), ('0 black', 9), ('1 pink', 16), ('1 black', 23), ('2 black', 6), ('2 pink', 30), ('3 pink', 14), ('3 black', 20)  i.e. two 'black's together '1 black', 23 and '2 black', 6 when it needs to alternate pink black etc. after '1 black', 23 should come 2 'pink', 30. perhaps there's a better way to number the keys.